# How to log request inputstream with HttpModule, then reset InputStream position

Tags: .net, httpmodule, inputstream

I am trying to log the contents of an http request, using an IHttpModule like so:

```
public class LoggingModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += ContextBeginRequest;
    }

    private void ContextBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = ((HttpApplication)sender).Request;
        string content;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        LogRequest(content)
    }
}
```

The problem is that after reading the input stream to the end, the InputStream seems to have either disappeared or more likely, the cursor is at the end of the stream.

I have tried `request.InputStream.Position = 0;` and `request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` but neither work.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I've worked out the problem: I think that calling dispose on the StreamReader must be killing the InputStream too.

Instead of using the StreamReader I did the following:

```
        var bytes = new byte[request.InputStream.Length];
        request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

So the complete code:

```
public class LoggingModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += ContextBeginRequest;
    }

    private void ContextBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = ((HttpApplication)sender).Request;

        var bytes = new byte[request.InputStream.Length];
        request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

        LogRequest(content)
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with the encoding there, I think you'll want it to be Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

Comment: I'd wasted a whole day befor I got what's wrong with my code. Thanks you a lot!

Answer (score 23):

Yes the StreamReader will close the supplied stream.

If you're on >v4.5, use a StreamReader constructor that leaves the stream open.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to make a small tweak to the answer provided by "cbp".  When using his code I just got zeros.  I moved setting the position to 0 above the read and now it works.

```
 var bytes = new byte[Request.InputStream.Length];
 Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
 Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

this answer did not work. it returns an array that contains null values.

```
        var bytes = new byte[request.InputStream.Length];
        request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

because the input stream consumed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [request filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.filter.aspx). Write a class deriving from [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) and register it as a filter.

Comment: Please elaborate how this is superior to other answers? Does it not require resetting the stream?

Answer (score -1):

sometime, `RequestFilter` don't run to method Read. It seem be W3WP don't read content of `httprequest` by normal way.

If you deploy `WEbservice` to server. Then use IHttpModule for catch it. Add `RequestFilter`.

But method `Read()` of RequestFilter don't run :P